# Rails test not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, integration-testing

I am just starting on rails. All functionalities of rails are running properly, but when I ran the command to run "rails test", it throws the following error. I tried to solve it by looking at similar questions where it was suggested to uninstall "arel" and "activerecord" gems and do bundle install, but sadly it did not work.
Please help me to resolve this error

```
MyApp$ rails test
/usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:33:in `require': cannot load such file -- arel/visitors/mysql (LoadError)
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/arel-9.0.0/lib/arel/visitors.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/arel-9.0.0/lib/arel.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activerecord-5.2.4/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
from /home/akhilr/Documents/Metastore/cpmetastore/cpmetastore/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `require'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:157:in `serve'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
from /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: is your rails app actually running? do you see the rails welcome page? why are you using rails 5 iso rails 7?

Comment: Hi @Les, It does work, I have created migrations and routes also.. all of them work without any problem. Only problem is with test. Could please shed some light on what is iso?